# java.sql.SQLWarning: [Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC]Database changed to X

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I'm using Hibernate 3.2.1  and database SQLServer2000

while I'm try to insert some data using my dao, some warning occurred like this:

```
java.sql.SQLWarning: [Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC]Database changed to BTN_SPP_DB
    at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BaseWarnings.createSQLWarning(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BaseWarnings.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BaseConnection.getWarnings(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter.logAndClearWarnings(JDBCExceptionReporter.java:22)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.closeConnection(ConnectionManager.java:443)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.aggressiveRelease(ConnectionManager.java:400)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.afterTransaction(ConnectionManager.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.afterTransactionCompletion(JDBCContext.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:119)
    at co.id.hanoman.btnmw.spp.dao.TagihanDao.save(TagihanDao.java:43)
    at co.id.hanoman.btnmw.spp.dao.TagihanDao.save(TagihanDao.java:1)
    at co.id.hanoman.btnmw.spp.dao.test.TagihanDaoTest.testSave(TagihanDaoTest.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.executeMethodBody(TestMethodRunner.java:99)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.runUnprotected(TestMethodRunner.java:81)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.BeforeAndAfterRunner.runProtected(BeforeAndAfterRunner.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.runMethod(TestMethodRunner.java:75)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.run(TestMethodRunner.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassMethodsRunner.invokeTestMethod(TestClassMethodsRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassMethodsRunner.run(TestClassMethodsRunner.java:35)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner$1.runUnprotected(TestClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.BeforeAndAfterRunner.runProtected(BeforeAndAfterRunner.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner.run(TestClassRunner.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
```

my hibernate initialization log is:

```
2010-04-26 22:54:05,203 INFO   [Version] Hibernate Annotations 3.3.0.GA 
2010-04-26 22:54:05,234 INFO   [Environment] Hibernate 3.2.1 
2010-04-26 22:54:05,234 INFO   [Environment] hibernate.properties not found 
2010-04-26 22:54:05,234 INFO   [Environment] Bytecode provider name : cglib 
2010-04-26 22:54:05,234 INFO   [Environment] using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling 
2010-04-26 22:54:05,343 INFO   [Configuration] configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml 
2010-04-26 22:54:05,343 INFO   [Configuration] Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml 
2010-04-26 22:54:05,406 DEBUG  [DTDEntityResolver] trying to resolve system-id [http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd] 
2010-04-26 22:54:05,406 DEBUG  [DTDEntityResolver] recognized hibernate namespace; attempting to resolve on classpath under org/hibernate/ 
2010-04-26 22:54:05,406 DEBUG  [DTDEntityResolver] located [http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd] in classpath 
2010-04-26 22:54:05,453 DEBUG  [Configuration] hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect 
2010-04-26 22:54:05,453 DEBUG  [Configuration] hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver 
2010-04-26 22:54:05,453 DEBUG  [Configuration] hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://12.56.11.65:1433;databaseName=BTN_SPP_DB 
2010-04-26 22:54:05,453 DEBUG  [Configuration] hibernate.connection.username=spp 
2010-04-26 22:54:05,453 DEBUG  [Configuration] hibernate.connection.password=spp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.igniterealtime.org/community/message/100481) says:

> This is a normal message from the MS jdbc driver when the database that you are using for JM isn''t the default database for the sql server account you are using to access the database. Pretty much ignore it - it''s completely harmless.